# select new in linq c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have one action in my controller of asp.net mvc project.

```
public JsonResult GetProductBySearch(string Q)
{
   JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
   var _product = from a in DataContext.SearchItem(Q)
                  select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
   jr.Data = _product.ToList();
   jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
   return jr;
}
```

I want to return this json data to the view of my project. It is works well in my view if I used "select new", But as I know, select new is using while we need the sub set of data. But in this query I want to get all the field from my table as below :

```
public JsonResult GetProductBySearch(string Q)
{
  JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
  var _product = from a in DataContext.SearchItem(Q)
                 select a;
  jr.Data = _product.ToList();
  jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
  return jr;
}
```

This is what I loop in view, It is work very well if  I used with select new.
But when I change to SELECT, the alert is not work.

```
 $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
     alert(1);
   $.each(data, function (index, proValByDep) {

   });
 });
```

Any ideas please.

Comment: There is no point in writing `from x in y select x`.

Comment: Giving some more information than just "it does not work" would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've edited it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

why using  "from a in DataContext.SearchItem(Q) select a"?

Can't you use `jr.Data=DataContext.SearchItem(Q).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to guess the problem as the question is a little unclear.

In the first example we see:

```
select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
```

In the second one the fieldnames won't be the same, so instead of `ProName` the resulting json will have `Name`.

Perhaps the javascript is expecting `ProName` and erroring out because it is undefined.

This doesn't explain why `alert(1);` doesn't work though.

Comment: Is the javascript shown in the question the actual javascript on your webpage?

Comment: Yes sure, it is in my view of asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Okay, well I'm not sure what the problem is then...  It looks like it should work.